# Filter string from JSON from asp.net web api using swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, asp.net-web-api

I am new to web development and Swift

I created a web api based on ASP.NET and I connected my ios app so I can do GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.

When I send GET request with specific ID number
I get output in Xcode as following:

```
Data:
Optional("{\"Id\":1,\"UserName\":\"codeinflash\",\"UserPassword\":\"Wldnrodxxxx\",\"UserEmail\":\"codeinflash@gmail.com\",\"Rebate\":0.00,\"MemCom\":123.44}")
```

Here is function in Swift:

```
//GET /api/account/{id}
@IBAction func GetAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    let _accountIdNumber = AccountIdNumber.text
    if (_accountIdNumber!.isEmpty){
        createAlert(title: "Warning", message: "Account ID # is required")
        return
    }

    let restEndPoinst: String = "http://tresmorewebapi2.azurewebsites.net/api/account/" + _accountIdNumber!;
    guard let url = URL(string: restEndPoinst) else {
        print("Error creating URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // api key need urlRequest.setValue(<#T##value: String?##String?#>, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKey")
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    var userEmail = ""
    var rebate = ""
    var memcom = ""


    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            (data, response, error) in
            print("Error:")
            print(error)
            print("response:")
            print(response)
            print("Data:")
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))

//////////////I think I need logic here to filter the data
userEmail = data.substring of find emailaddress
rebate = data.substring find users' rebate
memcom = same logic
then show alert window with his info and I will show his info on next page which is a Dashboard page view

    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Honestly I am not sure the Data is JSON data but the output in Xcode is in string.

My purpose is get uer's data and store in local variables that passes them to next view(Dashboard) in ios Swift.

Thank you!

**Added**
**Here is the task getting data from web api in login fuction swift**

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    var userEmail = ""
    var rebate = ""
    var memcom = ""

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            print("Error:")
            print(error)
            print("response:")
            print(response)
            print("Data:")
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))

            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String: AnyObject] ?? [:];
            userEmail = json?["UserEmail"] as? String ?? ""
            createAlert(title: "Got User Eamil Address!", message: userEmail)
    })

    task.resume()
```

But I get nothing in my alert view. The alert view working fine I tested.

**Here is my createAlert fuction in Swift**

```
func createAlert(title:String, message:String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (anction) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You need to convert your JSON data to a dictionary `let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]` don't forget to unwrap your data using `guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }`

Comment: BTW no need to use URLRequest for just a simple get. Jus use the URL

Comment: @LeoDabus so how do you store `UserEmail` value into my local `userEmail` using dictionary? Could you show me sample based on the first code line up there... Thanks!

Comment: `let dict = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]` and `let userEmail = dict["UserEmail"] as? String ?? ""`

Comment: @LeoDabus I get nothing.. I guess my parsing logic in the `task` is wrong.. could you please check my added code at last? Thanks!

Comment: Your create alert is placed at the wrong place. you need to move  `createAlert(title: "Got User Eamil Address!", message: userEmail)` to inside the closure just below the userEmail line. Where it is now It is getting called before the task completes

Comment: @LeoDabus If I put create alert inside the `task` nest. I get SIGABRT error.
in output says, `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`..

Comment: This has nothing to do with the json. BTW inside the closure you would need to add `self.createAlert...`

Comment: Yeah I added self.createAlert but sam errorr...

Comment: You need to post the method that it is causing the crash. BTW you should open a different question

Comment: `self.present(alert, animated.....)` thing inside of my `createAlert` causes error.. I will add this fuction at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have answer in comments already, but this is less "swifty" way, more readable for someone new to Swift (pay attention and try to understand what is going on and how you can make this more compact):

```
do {

    guard let unwrappedData = data else{
        //data is nil - handle case here
        return //exit scope
    }
    guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData) as? [String:AnyObject] else {
        //you cannot cast this json object to dictionary - handle case here
        return //exit scope
    }

    userEmail = dictionary["UserEmail"]
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.createAlert(title: "Got User Eamil Address!", message: userEmail)
    }
} catch _ {
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But could you check my updated code on last part of question?

Comment: @SteveKim you posted a question and got an answer - you cannot simply update your question with new question until you get your job done. Issue with creating alert is something completely different - I updated my answer, but you should make another question for that. At the end of your scope where you parse the json userEmail is with proper data. With the code you posted `createAlert` function is executed before finishing the dataTask.